# How to access XML element names from XmlEvent

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I am trying to access specific XML tag names from an Iterable Stream of XML Events. Is there a way as I can only find a way to print the text of each XmlEvent irrespective of tag/element name? Below my code.

```
Future<String> getDataFromXml() async {
  String xmlString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
      .loadString('assets/gpx/filename');

var events = parseEvents(xmlString).whereType<XmlTextEvent>();

Stream.fromIterable(events)
      .where((event) => event is XmlEvent)
      .cast<XmlEvent>()
      .forEach(print);
```

I understand how to access the elements from a parsed XML document (which is not a stream), but not from a stream of XML events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to avoid working with XML data. You should convert the XML data to JSON as possible as early. From this point of view, you can use the [xml2json](https://pub.dev/packages/xml2json) package.

```
  final myTransformer = Xml2Json();

  // Parse a simple XML string

  myTransformer.parse(xmlString);

  var jsonData = myTransformer.toParker();
```

Comment: May I ask why you made this recommendation? The deeper I go it seems that both have their benefits. XML seems more secure. Your thoughts @Akif ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, only `XmlTextEvent` (and `XmlCDATAEvent`) contain text. You can access the text by calling `text` on these events.

I don't quite understand what you want to do? `events` is an  `Iterable<XmlTextEvent>` with all the text events. Then you filter and cast that `Iterable<XmlTextEvent>` with a `Stream` to the superclass `XmlEvent`, which doesn't do anything. Just printing `events` would do the same.

Note that the package has two approaches to *event-based* XML parsing: the synchronous one that you are using with `Iterable<XmlEvent> parseEvents(String)` and the asynchronous one that works on Dart Streams `Stream<List<XmlEvent>> Stream.toXmlEvents()`. They both use the same event infrastructure, but the second one has much richer tooling. See the examples in the [tutorial](https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml/tree/nullsafety#event-driven).

Comment: Thank you @lukas-renggli - I do understand that these are all text events, that much was clear to me from the start. What wasn't clear to me was whether there is a way to access the tags of the events elements' tag names? It is now clear to me that the elements and their respective tags are disregarded.

Comment: What I want to do is perform calculations/aggregations or whatever analytics I want to on the data targeting specific tags.

Comment: Have a look at the last example in the linked tutorial section: If you annotate your event stream `withParentEvents()` you can access the `XmlStartElementEvent` as the `parentEvent` of each `XmlTextEvent`.

Comment: Thank you @lukas-renggli - That is where things weren't clear to me and hence me asking the question I did. Do you perhaps have a coding example in more or less the format I have submitted my snippet in?

Comment: Try something along the following lines to print the text within elements `<tag>`: `await Stream.fromIterable([xmlString]).toXmlEvents().withParentEvents().where((event) => event.parentEvent?.name == 'tag').forEach(print)`.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas Renggli - I will definitely do so....

Answer (score 0):

### Getting XML Inner Text From An Async Data Stream Using XmlEvents in Dart

I just added the inner text for each tag I needed to its own List:

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';
import 'package:xml/xml_events.dart';

printTagLists();

Future<void> printTagLists() async {
String xmlFileContents = "<ip>192.168.1.1</ip><mac>Mac1</mac><mac>Mac2</mac><host>hostName1</host>";

List<String> mac = <String>[];
List<String> ip = <String>[];
List<String> host = <String>[];
  
String tag = "";
String tagText = "";

  await Stream.fromIterable([
    xmlFileContents]).toXmlEvents().toXmlNodes().forEach((nodeStream) {
    tag = nodeStream.toString();
    tagText = nodeStream.first.innerText;
    (tag.contains("<mac>")
        ? mac.add(tagText)
        : (tag.contains("<ip>")
            ? ip.add(tagText)
            : (tag.contains("host") ? host.add(tagText) : "")));
  });

  print("This is mac $mac");
  print("This is ip $ip");
  print("This is host $host");
}
```

Produces:

```
This is mac [Mac1, Mac2]
This is ip [192.168.1.1]
This is host [hostName1]
```

Note, this won't work on nested tags.